# Java generic method how to return a generic inner class

Tags: java, generics

I know the title is quite messy, but I don't know how to explain this problem in just a few words.

Let:

```
public class A<T> {
    T foo;
    public A(T foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}

public class B {
    public A<T> getA() {
         ...
    }
}
```

Now, obviusly that B method won't even compile. The point is that I need a method in that B class that returns and A class, where the class T has to be passed to that method somehow so I can create an instance of T within such method in order to return an instance of A.

I tried something like:

```
public A getA(Class aClass) {
    return new A<aClass> ...
}
```

But that won't compile at all (aClass is unknown, it complains, and obviously it's right...)

So, how could I pass a class T to that method in order to create an instance of A inside it?

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your non-generic implementation has the blueprint for the fix: change this

```
public A getA(Class aClass) {
    return new A<aClass> ...
}
```

to this:

```
public <T> A<T> getA(Class<T> tClass) {
//     ^^^  ^^^           ^^^
    return new A<T>(tClass.newInstance()); // Assumes T has a default constructor
}
```

Comment: @marstran You are right, `aClass` is actually the class of `T`, not `A`, so there needs to be a `new` for `A` as well. Thank you!

Comment: Who removed my comment...?

Comment: @Fran And still, this is a pretty bad solution. It uses reflection for something you shouldn't need reflection for at all. It also assumes that `T` has a no-args constructor, which is something you can not be sure of at all.

Comment: @marstran I realized after seeing this answer that I do not need to pass the class as parameter at all, so I do not need reflection either, actually I can just create an instance of A<T> directly and that's perfect for my needs. Probably JF Meier answer is the one that better fitted my case, but as I hadn't explained it very well, I am not going to be picky about the details. The three answers were useful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to write a generic method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

```
public class B {
   public <T> A<T> getA() {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a type-parameter for your function. Remember that you also need a parameter for `A`'s constructor. This is the syntax:

```
public <T> A<T> getA(T t) {
    return new A<>(t);
}
```